# Wrong MongoDb query when using valueProcessor in react-querybuilder

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-querybuilder](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder)
in my project and recently using valueProcessor to change the value of field. The generated query result for SQL is OK but for MongoDb is not correct.

To simulate please visit [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-aryabhata-ex7f7w?file=/src/App.tsx).
I expect the following result :

```
{"$and":[{"firstName":{"$regex":"^jon"}},{"lastName":{"$in":["Vai","Vaughan"]}}]}
```

but this is the generated result:

```
{"$and":[jon,('Vai', 'Vaughan')]}
```

I wonder if I made a mistake or a bug.

**Update :** the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-aryabhata-ex7f7w?file=/src/App.tsx) for simulation was broken now I fixed it.

Comment: Can you add the full query object you're passing to formatQuery?

Comment: @JakeBoone  I made an update to this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CAUTION` note about `valueProcessor`s in the [Export documentation](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/api/export#value-processor) explains why this is happening:

> When producing non-SQL query language formats—including "mongodb", "cel", "spel", and "jsonlogic"—`valueProcessor` functions must produce the entire rule object (for MongoDB/JsonLogic) or rule string (for CEL/SpEL), not just the expression on the right-hand side of the operator like with SQL-based formats.
>
> This situation exists for backwards-compatibility reasons, but to increase the clarity of your own code we recommend using the `ruleProcessor` option which has the same interface and effect as valueProcessor for all non-SQL query language formats.

You must produce the entire rule, but your `valueProcessor` is only returning “jon” when the field is “firstName”.